# The closure of the complement of $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ with Lebesgue measure zero is $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I have been working on an excercise in measure theory for a few hours now, and although I have learned a lot, the answer to this problem avoids me.  It concerns proving the following assertion:

> Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ have Lebesgue measure zero. Then $\overline{\mathbb{R}^d \setminus A} = \mathbb{R}^d$,

where $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$ with respect to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

I have come to the conclusion that if I can show that $m(A) = 0$ implies that $A$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}^d$, the result follows, but I can't seem to prove this.

Comment: Note: $\mathbb{R}^d \setminus \overline{\mathbb{R}^d\setminus A} = \operatorname{int}(A)$.

Comment: It's not true that $m(A)=0$ implies $A$ is nowhere dense; the set $\mathbb Q$ of rational numbers is **everywhere** dense in $\mathbb R$ although it has measure $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ has Lebesgue measure zero, it cannot contain any open ball.  Therefore $A$ cannot be a neighborhood of any of its points.  It interior is empty, so the closure of its complement is all of $\mathbb{R}^d$.